# Code not working on Windows, 'json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)'

Tags: python, json, debugging

I am trying to run a code that takes in an input of URL strings of Github repo's and gets certain data regarding the repository.

I am using a venv, I've tried the exact same code on Linux and it works. When I try to run it on Windows 11 I get the following error:

```
  File "C:...\project-1\metrics.py", line 92, in __run_test
        object = json.loads(line)
      File "C:\Users\bbell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
        return _default_decoder.decode(s)
      File "C:\Users\bbell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
        obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
      File "C:\Users\bbell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
        raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

This is the code snippet for the part that gives the error:

```
enter code here
def __run_test(self, test_name, repository_path):
    output = subprocess.Popen(["semgrep", "--config", test_name, "--json", '-q', repository_path], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output.wait()

    line   = output.stdout.readline()
    object = json.loads(line)

    num_issues = len(object['results'])
    log.log_semgrep_test_results(repository_path.split("/")[1], test_name, num_issues)
    return num_issues
```

Comment: Try printing `line` to see what it contains.

Comment: BTW, did you read the description of the `debugging` tag? Does it really apply to your question?